# Flutter app not showing full display in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter

When i tried to build the app my app is not displayed in full screen in IOS Devices. In Android is working correctly.

Dont know what might be the issue. Below i have attached the screenshot.

Can someone please do this needfull.

[image: IPhone Version]

[image: Android Version]

Comment: Can you please add code snippet ?

Comment: Thats the confusing part, in Android its working fine and in IOS its not working properly, i am not getting any errors as well.

Comment: Please add any screen code where you are getting problems.. I prefer to add main.dart code

Comment: This is my info.plist

Comment: bro i need code not info.plist

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251880/discussion-between-rahul-variya-and-elam).

Comment: Have you used listView or gridView on this screen?

Comment: @Nams no i dint use.

Comment: So how do you scroll the screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Please add below line into info.plist***
this line will add launch storyboard on app start

```
   <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
   <string>LaunchScreen</string>
```

[image]

Comment: Don't forget to uninstall the app after updating info.plist